# How can I disable someone refreshing a page?

Tags: refresh

I just made a php code to add name,email,etc to be added into a table and when I click refresh, the same rows of information will appear and I don't want that to happen if the user will refresh the page...

ok, I have this page1.php where you can enter info and it will redirect you to page2.php but when I click F5 it enters the same info again

(I am just idiot-proofing it - what if someone wants to refresh the page or accidentally refreshes it, right?)

page1.php:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="page2.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php:

```
$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO sampletable (FirstName, LastName, Email)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[email]')";

if ($conn-> multi_query($sqlinsert) === TRUE) {

echo "New record created successfully.<br>";

} else {
echo "Error: " . $sqlinsert . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: The issue isn't the user refreshing the page, the issue is your code. You need to make your code bullet-proof so that if/when a user refreshes the page you don't have duplicate data.

Comment: you need to use a POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern. post to your form handler, then the form handler issues a redirect to another page, which is fetched via get. refreshing that page just does another GET, and won't re-submit the form.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll   Yeah, so how can I do it?

Comment: @MarcB how can I do that?

Comment: @Goldy you'd need to post some code for me to be able to help you.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: I edited it...please tell me if you need more